# Autoscale cells excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autoscale my table to always fit the window size. I'm trying to get the width of the excel window. I want to get a differens in some form when you resize the excel application. And then I am trying to save it to the variable "w", and compare it to the last time the windows changed size "w_old". And the problem is that I am not sure I am looking at the right place when I am looking at Application.Width because every time I run the script it runs the if statement even if I have not change the size of my excel window.

```
    Dim w As Long
    Dim w_old As Long
    w = Application.Width
    
    If (w <> w_old) Then
        Columns("A:K").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        Range("A1").Select
        w_old = w
    End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I can not get it to work" is quite vague. What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to get the width of the excel window. I want to get a differens in some form when you resize the excel application. And then I am trying to save it to the variable "w", and compare it to the last time the windows changed size "w_old". And the problem is that I am not sure I am looking at the right place when I am looking at Application.Width. @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70600093/edit) to clarify it. And please include a _complete minimal reproducible_ example of your code.

Comment: I've edited my question, but the code is what it is. It is not more then what I wrote @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: Your code does not assign a value to `w_old` before the if statement

Comment: I know,doesn't it get 0 then? So after the first run of the scipt it has the same value as w until I change the size of the window?

Comment: Variable values reset each time you run a sub...

Comment: Oh, that explains alot. Is there a way to store a value or do I need to set it to a cell and then get it next time??

Comment: You can save values between executions by putting them in a [Module-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level) variable. Put the `Dim` line at the top of the code module, above any `Sub`. These values are only reset when the workbook closes.

Comment: Thank you! @Toddleson